# Faster sql query then join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big table with more than 10,000 rows and it will grow to 1,000,000 in the near future, and I need to run a query which gives back a Time value for each keyword for each user. I have one right now which is quite slow because I use left joins and it needs one subquery / keyword:

```
SELECT rawdata.user, t1.Facebook_Time, t2.Outlook_Time, t3.Excel_time
FROM
rawdata left join
(SELECT user, sec_to_time(SuM(time_to_sec(EndTime-StartTime))) as 'Facebook_Time'
FROM rawdata 
WHERE MainWindowTitle LIKE '%Facebook%'
GROUP by user)t1 on rawdata.user = t1.user left join
(SELECT user, sec_to_time(SuM(time_to_sec(EndTime-StartTime))) as 'Outlook_Time'
FROM rawdata 
WHERE MainWindowTitle LIKE '%Outlook%'
GROUP by user)t2 on rawdata.user = t2.user left join
(SELECT user, sec_to_time(SuM(time_to_sec(EndTime-StartTime))) as 'Excel_Time'
FROM rawdata 
WHERE MainWindowTitle LIKE '%Excel%'
GROUP by user)t3 on rawdata.user = t3.user
```

The table looks like this:

```
WindowTitle | StartTime | EndTime | User
------------|-----------|---------|---------
Form1       | DateTime  | DateTime| user1
Form2       | DateTime  | DateTime| user2
...         | ...       | ...     | ...
Form_n      | DateTime  | DateTime| user_n
```

The output should looks like this:

```
User   | Keyword   | SUM(EndTime-StartTime)
-------|-----------|-----------------------
User1  | 'Facebook'|              00:34:12
User1  | 'Outlook' |              00:12:34
User1  | 'Excel'   |              00:43:13
User2  | 'Facebook'|              00:34:12
User2  | 'Outlook' |              00:12:34
User2  | 'Excel'   |              00:43:13
...    | ...       | ...  
User_n | ...       | ...
```

And the question is, which is the fastest way in MySQL to do this?

Comment: Use the `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` keywords to learn what your query is doing

Comment: You can't index a pattern in the middle of a column, such as `LIKE '%Outlook%'` (fulltext indices aside). As long as you keep using that condition, it'll be slow.

Comment: @DCoder you can tell I am not a DBA - I do not think in sets and your comment is so obvious now :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I know it is slow because the wildcards, but they are unavoidable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your wildcard searches are probably what's slowing it down the most, since you can't really utilize indexes on those fields.  Also if you can avoid doing sub-queries and just do a straight join, it might help, but the wildcard searches are far worse.  Is there anyway you could change the table to have a categoryName or categoryID that can have an index and not require a wildcard search?  Like "where categoryName = 'Outlook'"

To optimize the data in your tables, add a categoryID (ideally this would reference a separate table, but let's just use arbitrary numbers for this example):

```
alter table rawData add column categoryID int not null

alter table rawData add index (categoryID)
```

Then populate the categoryID field for the existing data:

```
update rawData set categoryID=1 where name like '%Outlook%'
update rawData set categoryID=2 where name like '%Facebook%'
-- etc...
```

Then change your insert to follow the same rules.

Then make your SELECT query like this (changed wild cards to categoryID):

```
SELECT rawdata.user, t1.Facebook_Time, t2.Outlook_Time, t3.Excel_time
FROM
rawdata left join
(SELECT user, sec_to_time(SuM(time_to_sec(EndTime-StartTime))) as 'Facebook_Time'
FROM rawdata 
WHERE categoryID = 2
GROUP by user)t1 on rawdata.user = t1.user left join
(SELECT user, sec_to_time(SuM(time_to_sec(EndTime-StartTime))) as 'Outlook_Time'
FROM rawdata 
WHERE categoryID = 1
GROUP by user)t2 on rawdata.user = t2.user left join
(SELECT user, sec_to_time(SuM(time_to_sec(EndTime-StartTime))) as 'Excel_Time'
FROM rawdata 
WHERE categoryID = 3
GROUP by user)t3 on rawdata.user = t3.user
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The wildcards are neccessary because the records stores window titles and there could be anything and I can search for keywords only.

Comment: However there are programs, which not requires keywords, cause I have the process name too, but in the case of a web browser I need deeper investigation like process name.

Comment: Could you do this wild card logic when you insert the records and use that logic to determine some sort of categoryID?  Then index categoryID.

Comment: Yes I can, and I can do it in excel also, but I'm curious to possibilities in sql?

Comment: Well doing this at the time of insert would probably be the most normalized/efficient way to handle it in SQL.  I think you would notice a significant performance increase if you could change all your sub-query's "WHERE" clauses to search on an indexed categoryID.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider it at the next program release :) I think I will write an sql procedure for this, to convert Raw Data to an indexed table. Thanks for your idea!

Comment: Sounds good - I updated my answer above to include the steps.  Hope this helps!